# Regular expression how to prevent match if followed by a specific word. Something like first character inclusive lookahead?

Tags: regex, perl, expression, regex-lookarounds

I am using a regular expression to match where conditions in a SQL query.

I want `WHERE <ANY CONDITION>`, but with the exception of `WHERE ROWNUM <WHATEVER>`.
So I do not want `ROWNUM` to appear after the `WHERE` keyword.

I did use [Lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve that. My regex is `WHERE (.*(?! ROWNUM )+)`. The problem is, it still matches `WHERE ROWNUM < 1000`. If I delete the space before `ROWNUM` in the regex, then any column with a name ending with `ROWNUM` won't match. If I delete the space after `WHERE` then it would match even if there is no space after the `WHERE` keyword. However, if there are two spaces or any other character between `ROWNUM` and the `WHERE` keyword (might be a condition), then it is ok. So if `ROWNUM` is first in the condition my regex does not work.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
WHERE(?!.*\bROWNUM\b).*
```

which will match `WHERE .*`, *unless* the `.*` contains a `ROWNUM` that is surrounded by word boundaries. (`\b`, "word boundary", is a zero-width assertion denoting a position that is preceded by a letter or digit or underscore *or* followed by a letter or digit or underscore, *but not both*.)

Comment: Wouldnt this cause not matching WHERE ABROWNUM ? I want that to match.

Comment: @brhneser: Fear not: `WHERE ABROWNUM` would still match, because then the `.*` would start with `AB`, and the negative lookahead doesn't count that.

Comment: Oh well, well i just got what you mean. But this is not what i want. This will still match "WHERE a = 5 and rownum < 1000" for example. I don't want rownum appear anywhere after "WHERE". Thats why i use .* before negative lookahead. @ruakh

Comment: @brhneser: Ah, understood. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Elegant solution :) I was trying the use word boundries in a proper way, couldn't do it :) Can't think simple after reading regular expressions in detail :) 

Thanks

Comment: well erm, thinking on it a bit brought me back to my problem :) lol, i actually am capturing the conditions by grouping. I mean if it is WHERE a=5 and b=3 i want to extract a=5 and b=3 bits of it. So how do i group the expression withing negative lookahead ? 

Is it a bit tricky or it is me ? @ruakh

Comment: Well, one option is to change the `.*` to `\s+(.*)`, so that `$1` is `a=5 and b=3`, and then `split` by `/\s+AND\s+/i` to get that as a list.