# regular expression to match string of characters only if it is not followed by a specific character

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regular expression which will match a string only if it doesn't followed by a forward slash (/) character and I want to match whole string.

For example below string should match

```
/Raj/details/002-542545-1145457
```

but not this one

```
/Raj/details/002-542545-1145457/show
```

I tried to use [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this as specified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9587930/324900).

My code is like this.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("/.*/details/(?!.*/)");
matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("success");
} else {
System.out.println("failure");
}
```

It is giving failure. But if I use `matcher.find()` then it is giving success.

Please help me understanding why it is not matching and a reg-exp to achieve this?

Comment: question is very unclear..u want to match only those string that dont end with / then y is ur second example invalid

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
^/[^/]+/details/[^/]+$
```

will match

```
/Raj/details/002-542545-1145457
```

but not

```
/Raj/details/002-542545-1145457/show
```

Comment: But it is also matching this /Raj/details/002-542545-1145457/show/details/dsdf

Comment: So did yours. Are you asking for `^/[^/]+/details/[^/]+?$`, then?

Comment: Thanks garyh & @ikegami, it worked fine. But why it is reluctant quantifier (+?) for the last part and greedy quantifier (+) for the first part?

Comment: @Reddy, Greediness is irrelevant in this expression. You can use both `+` and `+?` in both places. (Well, if the string was longer, it could affect performance, but it won't affect what will match.) I didn't mean to use `.+?` in my regexp; I copied and pasted it from garyh without noticing. I have removed the non-greedy modifier from the answer.

Comment: @ikegami, If string is longer reluctant will be more performant right?

Comment: @Reddy, If either is faster, I imagine that would be the one.

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is not doing what you are expecting it to do. You are missing a part of the expression that captures the numerical data after `/details/`.

Your regex is positive for `.find()` because there is a match inside the string for your current expression, but the string does not match the expression entirely which is why `.matches()` doesn't work.

Your current expression is not a greedy search, it stops matching as soon as it gets to `/details/`. It fails the match if there is a `/` after `/details/`, so it is not matching the characters between `/details/` and any potential `/` - in your examples, the numerical data. Which causes `.matches()` to fail, even though there is still a positive match.

If you want it to match the whole string up to and including the numbers but nothing afterwards, the following regex should work: `/.*/details/[0-9\-]*(?!.*/)` - with that both `.find()` and `.matches()` will return positive, as the expression is now matching everything up to the potential `/`.

Comment: Yup, you were missing a part of the regex. Your regex was not matching characters after details/ (the numbers), it was just matching content before the numbers which wasn't followed by a /. It's not a greedy search. If you use my or @garyh 's expression, you should get the expected result.

Comment: +1, Thank you for explaining difference between find() and matches(). For other part of the question, garyh's expression looks much better hence accepting that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You regex looks OK. `matcher()` only matches the whole String, while `find()` matches next substring inside your String.